# Why is flexbox justify-content space-between not working?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a comment section where the user can enter comments, it automatically displays comments and the time the comment was entered.

I want author name to be to the left and date to the right and it should be responsive using flex-box

Here is jsfiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/68vt3c7s/

Here is what I would like to have

[image]

Here is a snippet of what i have:

```css
.comments-description {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 23px 0px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #EBEBEB;
}

.comments_details {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  margin-top: 27px;
}

.comments_wrapper {
  padding: 32px 21px;
}

.comments-photo img {
  border-radius: 300px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  position: relative;
  top: 37px;
}
```

```html
<div class="comments-description">
  <div class="comments-photo"><img alt="" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/84.jpg"></div>
  <div class="comments_wrapper">
    <div class="comments_details">
      <h1>Mike Ross</h1>
      <span class="days">4 minutes ago</span>
    </div>
    <div class="comments_text">
      <p>dingi
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

what do I need to change to get what I want ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add for `.comments_wrapper` the `flex: auto;` in order to align time to right

Means:

```
.comments_wrapper {
    padding: 32px 21px;
    flex: auto; /* here I added */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help.

```
.comments_wrapper{
    -webkit-box-flex:1;
    -ms-flex-positive:1;
    flex-grow:1;
}
```

Comment: what about other browsers?

Answer (score 0):

`comments_wrapper` selector not taking rest of the place that's why you not seeing the effect. Try like following way:

```
.comments_wrapper {
    padding: 32px 21px;
    flex-grow: 1; /* Key Line */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the width of the .comments_wrapper

```
.comments-description {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    padding: 23px 0px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #EBEBEB;
}

.comments_details {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    margin-top: 27px;
}

.comments_wrapper {
    padding: 32px 21px;
    width: 100%; /*add this*/
}

.comments-photo img {
    border-radius: 300px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    position: relative;
    top: 37px;
}
.days{
margin-left: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `flex: auto;` to `.comments_wrapper` css

```
.comments_wrapper {
   padding: 32px 21px;
   flex: auto;
}
```

```css
.comments-description {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 23px 0px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #EBEBEB;
}

.comments_details {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  margin-top: 27px;
}

.comments_wrapper {
  padding: 32px 21px;
  flex: auto;
}

.comments-photo img {
  border-radius: 300px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  position: relative;
  top: 37px;
}
```

```html
<div class="comments-description">
  <div class="comments-photo"><img alt="" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/84.jpg"></div>
  <div class="comments_wrapper">
    <div class="comments_details">
      <h1>Mike Ross</h1>
      <span class="days">4 minutes ago</span>
    </div>
    <div class="comments_text">
      <p>dingi
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```